# How to Hide/Remove the header from output csv via Powershell script

Tags: powershell, csv

I am using Psping to check the latency of IPs with port and export the result CSV without display the header.

I have tried -select skip 1 it seems not working but with errors.

```
function CheckLatency 
{
  param([string[]]$servers)
  foreach ($server in $servers) 
  {
    $times = [ordered]@{ Server = "$server";TimeStamp = (Get-Date -f "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"); Minimum = 0; Maximum = 0; Average = 0; } 
    $results = & "c:\users\test\desktop\psping.exe" -n 1 $server 2>&1 | select-string "Minimum" 
    if ($results) {
      $results = $results.tostring() -split "," 
      foreach ($result in $results) 
      {
        $result = ($result -replace "ms","").trim() 
        $parsed = $result -split " "
        switch ($parsed[0]) 
        {
          "Minimum" {$times.Minimum = $parsed[2]}
          "Maximum" {$times.Maximum = $parsed[2]}
          "Average" {$times.Average = $parsed[2]}
        }
      }
      new-object -type PSObject -prop $times
    }
  }
}

$csvFile = "C:\users\test\desktop\check$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-hhmmss).csv"
CheckLatency 8.8.8.8:443,8.8.8.8:80 | Export-CSV -LiteralPath $csvFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Output with header

[image: Please help remove the header]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Export-Csv` *invariably* includes a header row (the list of property names of the output objects).

Your only option is to remove that row after the fact, using plain-text processing:

```
$csvFile = "C:\users\test\desktop\check$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-hhmmss).csv"

# ... your code that calls 
# Export-CSV -LiteralPath $csvFile -NoTypeInformation

# Read the resulting file as an array of lines, skip the 1st line,
# and write the result back to the file.
(Get-Content -LiteralPath $csvFile) | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content -LiteralPath $csvFile
```

Note the `(...)` around the `Get-Content` call, which ensures that the file is read in full before its lines are sent through the pipeline, allowing the input file to be rewritten in the same pipeline.
Do note that there's a slight chance of the file getting corrupted if the write process is interrupted.

Note that Windows PowerShell uses ANSI encoding by default with `Set-Content`, whereas `Export-Csv` uses ASCII; use `-Encoding` as needed.
PowerShell *Core*, fortunately, defaults to BOM-less UTF-8 consistently.