# How to store output of script using powershell to azure storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-automation

please help to store my output result to storage account using powershell in azure automation account such as identify the list of untagged resources, i need to the get the result list as csv into the storage account. Kindly let me know

Answer (score 0):

***You can use the below Azure Powershell command to get the output of untagged tags into csv file:***

```
Get-AzResource | Where-Object { $_tags.count -eq 0 } | Export-Csv  -Path "C:\New folder\test.csv"
```

[image]

***Output of command :***

[image]

***Then you can upload the above csv file using portal:***

First click on storage account then click on container then on your container then upload the file

[image]

[image]

***References:***

[Azure CLI(Export azure resource to csv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72964714/azure-cliexport-azure-resource-to-csv/72966043#72966043)

Comment: @RithwikBojja- thank you for the answer. Is there a way to remove the **#TYPE** information header from the CSV output, in my code i have tried using  **-NoTypeInformation** getting this error 
 **System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'NoTypeInformation'**                                                        Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check this [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57318844/how-to-hide-remove-the-header-from-output-csv-via-powershell-script).